# keep that row if it contains any "TRUE"

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean-logic

I have a table look like this one

```
    C1      C2      C3      C4      C5....    
R1  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
R2  FALSE   FALSE   NA      TRUE
R3  NA      NA      NA      TRUE
R4  NA      FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
R5  NA      NA      NA      NA
.
.
.
```

I want to keep all rows which contain at least one TRUE. In this table, R1, R2 and R3 need to be kept. Then, I can extract another column(C21)'s value from this same table.

Please give me some advise, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Example
x <- 
  matrix(c(FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA), 
         nrow = 5, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(paste0("R", 1:5), paste0("C", 1:4)))
x
#       C1    C2    C3    C4
# R1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# R2 FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
# R3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# R4    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE
# R5    NA    NA  TRUE FALSE

# apply the 'any()' function to the rows, this will return true if there is at
# least one TRUE in the row

apply(x, 1, any)
# R1   R2   R3   R4   R5 
# TRUE   NA   NA   NA TRUE 

# use 'which' to get the row index

which(apply(x, 1, any)) 
# R1 R5 
#  1  5 

# subset the matrix
idx <- which(apply(x, 1, any))

x[idx, ]
#       C1    C2   C3    C4
# R1 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
# R5    NA    NA TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I am able to use this one to get the row that I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
apply(X = df1, 1, any)
```

will give you a logical vector, that you can then use accordingly

i.e. `df1[which(apply(df1, 1, any)), ]`

Comment: no difference .. it is basically just a one-liner of Peters answer; basically it just took me a while to elaborate on my earlier comment (to apply the any function) below

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`df1 & !is.na(df1)`), check if the sum is greater than 0, use that logical vector to subset the rows.

```
Subdf <- df1[rowSums(df1 & !is.na(df1)) >0,]
Subdf
#      C1    C2   C3   C4
#R1 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#R2 FALSE FALSE   NA TRUE
#R3    NA    NA   NA TRUE
```

Or we can use the `na.rm=TRUE` in `rowSums`

```
df1[rowSums(df1, na.rm=TRUE) > 0,]
```

We can extract the 'C21' column by `Subdf$C21` or `Subdf[['C21']]` (if the initial dataset is `data.frame`) or `Subdf[, 'C21']` for `matrix` (in the example, I didn't have 21 columns)

Comment: They may have a matrix, in which case the first two extractors you mention won't work.

Comment: @Frank Yes, I was thinking about adding that line.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: one could also just  apply function "any" to the table